# How to automatically notify an user when his/her auction ends?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, cron

I'm building an auction site (much like eBay) where you can create auctions with a given base value and a duration.

This is done with PHP and MySQL essentially. In this defined period of time, users can place bids.

What means should I use to be able to known asynchronously when the auction ends in order to notify the auctioneer (calling a PHP script or trigger another kind of event)?

**EDIT:**

I have a cronjob up and running (every 5 minutes). My PHP script calls a MySQL stored procedure that selects all invalid auctions (AuctionEndDateTime < NOW()) and updates them as closed.

Since I'm doing  a `SELECT` in a stored procedure, I was expecting to have the updated rows returned but it's only returning the first `SELECT`that I do to fech the current timestamp.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE closeAuctions ()
BEGIN
SELECT @TIMESTAMP_NOW := NOW();
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT *  FROM Auctions WHERE auction_deadline < @TIMESTAMP_NOW AND auction_closed = '0' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE Auctions SET auction_closed = '1' WHERE auction_deadline < @TIMESTAMP_NOW;
COMMIT;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Returns:

```
+-------------------------+
| @TIMESTAMP_NOW := NOW() |
+-------------------------+
| 2013-07-26 15:57:20     |
+-------------------------+
```

I want the updated rows because they contain information that I need to notify the auctioneers and I was trying to do this with a stored procedure so I would just make one trip to the database.

**SOLVED:**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE closeAuctions ()
BEGIN
DECLARE now TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT *  FROM Auctions WHERE auction_deadline < now AND auction_closed = '0' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE Auctions SET auction_closed = '1' WHERE auction_deadline < now;
COMMIT;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Its better to add your solution as an answer instead of adding it the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a script and inside the script query auctions from database where end time is equal to now.
Then loop through the list of found auctions and send emails to owners.

To automate this process, run this script via a `CRON` every minute or so.

Comment: Not sure `=NOW()` is a good thing. What happen if the auction finish at `09:56:35` and the script run at `09:56:00` AND `09:57:00`?

Comment: I'd possibly do it via a cron if you do it inline once the site is full it'll hang the load searching the auctions until its finished looping and emailing. far better to cron it even if it runs every 5 minutes

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tblauctions WHERE AuctionEndDateTime <= NOW() AND AuctionAlreadyExpired=0` store the end date time when auction is created then all you need to do is do it as part of your select and later on udpate an expired/comeplted flag as in my example

Comment: Not necessarily the now function, just use timestamps for both DB and in script and then do the comparison

Comment: time stamps are bad m'kay stick with datetime field type

Comment: @FooBar With proper framing you can set it up to capture all the events that are eligible to be fired but haven't been triggered yet.

Comment: @tadman i agree with you. I only said if he uses a strict statement he might miss some results